# How to read memory with segment addressing mode in lldb on x86-64?

Tags: x86-64, lldb, thread-local-storage, addressing-mode

While debugging a process with `lldb` I get to this assembly instruction:

```
->  0x7ffff79c5187 <+7>:   movq   %fs:(%r14), %r14
```

Or in intel syntax:

```
->  0x7ffff79c5187 <+7>:   mov    r14, qword ptr fs:[r14]
```

Contents of the registers:

```
(lldb) register read fs
      fs = 0x0000000000000000
(lldb) register read r14
     r14 = 0xffffffffffffff08
```

I don't know how to calculate what address is being accessed here (just reading `0xffffffffffffff08` fails), so I would like to use the same addressing mode in order to get the address that is accessed here (then set a watchpoint).

I tried many address expressions, but they are all apparently invalid.
Here are some of the ways I tried to read that memory:

```
x "$fs:($r14)"
x "%fs:(%r14)"
x "fs:(r14)"
x $rs
x $fs
memory read %fs:(%r14)
memory read 'qword ptr $fs:[$r14]'
memory read '%fs:(%r14)'
memory read '$fs:($r14)'
memory read '*(int **)$fs:($r14)'
memory read '*(int **)$fs:($r14)'
memory read '*(int *)$fs:($r14)'
```

But I always get

```
error: invalid start address expression.
error: address expression <my address expression> evaluation failed
```

Comment: Can you ask `lldb` for the FS base address?  That's what you want, not the value of FS itself (which is probably going to be `0`, not even a selector index into the GDT, as the kernel will have set the FS base via `wrmsr` or `wrfsbase` in 64-bit mode.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Sure, any tips on how to do that? I'm googling it but haven't found a way yet.

Comment: I don't know if there's an LLDB command for it; I haven't used it.  I seem to recall a recent Q&A about GDB getting segment bases.  But the keyword to search for is "fs base".